# RTextTools: Understanding 'algorithm_summary'

Tags: r, text-classification

I was trying to understand how `RTextTools` offer a great set of functions for classifying documents.

However, while running an inbuilt dataset, I am unable to understand how to interpret the following table. (I wonder why there are 10 rows)

```
        SVM_PRECISION   SVM_RECALL  SVM_FSCORE  MAXENTROPY_PRECISION    MAXENTROPY_RECALL   MAXENTROPY_FSCORE
2           NaN             0               NaN                     0.5                 1               0.67    
12          NaN             0               NaN                     0                   0               NaN
14          NaN             0               NaN                     NaN                 0               NaN
15          NaN             0               NaN                     0                   0               NaN
16          NaN             0               NaN                     0.33                0.2             0.25
17          NaN             0               NaN                     NaN                 0               NaN
19         0.08         1               0.15                    0.14                0.5             0.22
20          NaN             0               NaN                     0.38                0.75            0.5
24          NaN             0               NaN                     NaN                 0               NaN
31          NaN             0               NaN                     NaN                 0               NaN
```

The above table can be produced as

```
library(RTextTools)
data(NYTimes)
data <- NYTimes[sample(1:3100,size=100,replace=FALSE),]
matrix <- create_matrix(cbind(data["Title"],data["Subject"]), language="english", 
                        removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=FALSE, weighting=tm::weightTfIdf)
container <- create_container(matrix,data$Topic.Code,trainSize=1:75, testSize=76:100, 
                              virgin=FALSE)
models <- train_models(container, algorithms=c("MAXENT","SVM"))
results <- classify_models(container, models)
analytics <- create_analytics(container, results)
summary(analytics)
alg_summary <- analytics@algorithm_summary
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTextTools/RTextTools.pdf):

> `algorithm_summary` Object of class "data.frame": stores precision,
>   recall, and F-score statistics for each algorithm, **broken down by
>   label**

There are 27 distinct topic codes in the full NYTimes dataset, and your sample probably contains 10 of them. Hence the 10 rows.

Comment: `length(unique(NYTimes$Topic.Code))` is 27. And these topic codes correspond to labels.